# ¿Cómo extraer valores ajustados en lmer solo para efectos fijos?

Tags: r

Necesitaría extraer los valores ajustados de un modelo usando lmer pero
solo para la porción fija del modelo y no para porción aleatoria. Busqué en muchos post pero no logro encontrar una solución. Cualquier ayuda es muy bienvenida.

Por ejemplo:

```
library("lme4")

fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fitted(fm1) # Asi obtenemos los valores ajustados
```

La función `fitted(fm1)` me da los valores ajustados pero incluye la porción fija y aleatoria del modelo.

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con esto, pero por lo que leí rápidamente, entiendo que podría ser algo así: `model.matrix(<modelo>, type = "fixed") %*% fixef(<modelo>)`, donde obviamente `<modelo>` es tu variable del modelo.

Comment: Chequea esto: https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/fitted-values-in-LMER-for-the-fixed-effects-only-td835667.html

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Funcionó perfecto!

Comment: Me alegro, edito un poco tu pregunta y dejo la respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según uno de los autores del paquete [`lme4`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf), Douglas Bates, en este [hilo](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/fitted-values-in-LMER-for-the-fixed-effects-only-td835667.html#none), la forma de calcular esto sería haciendo:

```
model.matrix(fm1, type = "fixed") %*% fixef(fm1)
```

o en su defecto, también:

```
getME(fm1, "X")  %*% fixef(fm1)
```

Comment: Una nueva consulta. Hay forma de usar los coeficientes de los factores fijos sobre un nuevo dataset para predecir nuevos valores?